# C++ Dynamic Arrays Index and Capacity problems

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic-arrays

My home work is to ask me to build a dynamic array and with other functions. I've managed to complete the rest of the problems but there is one bug I don't understand...

Currently if I set `D[0]=11` and `D[1]=12`, no matter how big the array is, all values in the array will turned into 12, along with the capacity with it will become 12.

These are the codes I think is relevant below, I will provide more per request.

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRcs2.png)

```
template <class dynElem>
class dynarr {
  private:
    int capacity;
    dynElem *A;
  public:
    dynarr() : capacity(0), A(NULL){};
    dynarr(int N): capacity(N), A(new dynElem[N]){}
    dynarr(const dynarr<dynElem> &other);
    ~dynarr();
    dynarr<dynElem> & operator=( const dynarr<dynElem> &other);
    dynElem & operator[](int ndx) throw(InvalidIndex);
    int getCapacity();
    void reserve(int newcap);
};

template <class dynElem>
dynarr<dynElem>::dynarr(const dynarr<dynElem> &other)
{
    capacity = other.capacity;
    A = new dynElem[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < other.capacity; i++) {
        A[i] = other.A[i];
    }
}

template <class dynElem>
dynarr<dynElem>::~dynarr()
{
    delete[] A;
}
```

test.cpp

```
int main()
{
  dynarr<int> D(15);
  std::cout << "The capacity of D is " << D.getCapacity() << std::endl;
  D[0] = 11;
  D[1] = 12;
  std::cout << "D[0] = " << D[0] << std::endl; //12
  std::cout << "D[1] = " << D[1] << std::endl; //12
  std::cout << "The capacity of D is " << D.getCapacity() << std::endl; //12
  return 0;
}
```

extra codes by the request of @someprogrammerdude :

```
template <class dynElem>
dynElem & dynarr<dynElem>::operator[](int ndx) throw(InvalidIndex)
{
    if (ndx < 0) {
        throw InvalidIndex("Array Index is negative");
    }
    else if (ndx > capacity) {
        throw InvalidIndex("Array Index is too large");
    }
}

template <class dynElem>
int dynarr<dynElem>::getCapacity()
{
  return capacity;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The idiomatic way to create a _dynamic array_ in c++ is to use `std::vector` with the required type.

Comment: Please show us the indexing operator `operator[]`, as well as the `dynElement` class and the `getCapacity` function. In short, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: NOTE: the codes in the dynarr class are provided by my prof. I only wrote the copy constructor and the destructor

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude here you go.

Comment: And where does your `operator[]` function actually *return* anything?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But... but... NIH guarantees job security!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that's only for throwing exceptions.....?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Believe me it doesn't ;-)! There's no such thing like _job guarantees_.

Comment: No. You say that it returns a reference to a `dynElem` object. If you don't return anything, you will have *undefined behavior*. In your case it should probably return `A[ndx]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude aHA!  silly me.   Always making some idiotic mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm amazed that your code actually **compiled without warning** (my compiler would shout at me). You 'forgot' to return a value from `operator[]`. Here is what you should have done.

```
template <class dynElem>
dynElem & dynarr<dynElem>::operator[](int ndx) throw(InvalidIndex)
{
    if (ndx < 0) {
        throw InvalidIndex("Array Index is negative");
    }
    else if (ndx > capacity) {
        throw InvalidIndex("Array Index is too large");
    }
    return A[ndx];   // here we return the element.
}
```

Btw, in modern C++ you would code this slightly differently (apart from the fact that you would never re-implement `std::vector`):

```
template<typename T>
class dynarr {
    std::size_t _capacity =0;    // set default values for initialisation
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> ptr;    // don't worry about de-allocation
  public:
    dynarr() = default;          // no need to define a destructor either
    dynarr(std::size_t N)
      : _capacity(N), ptr(new T[N]) {}
    dynarr(const dynarr&);
    dynarr& operator=(const dynarr&);
    T& operator[](size_t i);                // no need for throw()
    T const& operator[](size_t i) const;    // version for const access
    size_t capacity() const noexcept
      { return _capacity; }
    void reserve(size_t new_capacity);
};
```